# PST(Personal Storage Table or Personal Folder File) data dissappears when opening with outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi

I am using C++ and extended mapi to copy the contents of a mailbox to a pst programmatically.In the end the pst file is created and it shows the correct size but as soon as i try to open it with outlook the data in pst file disappears.After i run my program the PST size is 10 MB and when i try to open it with outlook 2007 it shows it as an empty pst file.Can anyone please help me in this one.

I am using MS Exchange 2007 32 bit on windows Server 2003 with outlook 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your app does not cleanly terminate and the PST provider does not get a chance to commit the data and write a special flag that would tell it on startup that it was shut down cleanly.
Do you release all MAPI objects first?
Do you call IMAPISession::Logoff?
Do you call MAPIUninitialize?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but when i copy a single folder in the PST then the data doesn't disappear on opening in outlook even if its multiple folders.But when i copy the entire folder then there is a problem i am using IMapiFolder::Copy method to copy the folder.

Comment: Thanks actually i was not releasing an Imapifolder pointer.But the same code was working for exchange server 2003.